# Swift: change a variable based on if 1 of 6 buttons are pressed? Syntax?

Tags: swift

So I have created some "pseudo code" for my problem below >

My variable, playerMark, needs to be equal to a different set of images depending on if 1 of 6 buttons have been pressed, with the red images ("Red_x" and "Red_o") being the default. I really just need some help with the syntax of my pseudo code because I can't make `if blueBtnClicked` into a boolean to set it to `true` and I don't know how else to write it. Also, I don't think a naming system is the right way to go with this.

Please thoroughly explain all suggestions, thanks! My code:

```
func setImgforCircle(spot:Int, player:Int) {
        var playerMark = player == 1 ? "Red_x" : "Red_o"

    if blueBtnClicked(sender: UIButton.self) = true {  // This block is the pseudo code
        playerMark = player == 1 ? "Blue_x" : "Blue_o" //
    }

    plays[spot] = player
    switch spot {
    case 1:
        circle1.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 2:
        circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 3:
        circle3.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 4:
        circle4.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 5:
        circle5.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 6:
        circle6.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 7:
        circle7.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 8:
        circle8.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 9:
        circle9.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

    default:
        circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    }

}
```

Blue button:

```
@IBAction func blueBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        gameboard.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_gb")
        resultsView.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_results")
        colorsView.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_Colors")
        colorsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightTextColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        resetBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightTextColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
```

Comment: what is the type of `blueBtnClicked`? show the code

Comment: blueBtnClicked is an IBAction that I hooked up (I edited my question). I just need to change the values in playerMark when the blue button is clicked.

Comment: what do you expect from `blueBtnClicked`? it does not return anything

Comment: That is because I do not know how to write the code that would return something. I need to know how to change the playerMark line when the blue button is clicked so that instead of "Red_x" and "Red_o", playerMark can return "Blue_x" and "Blue_o". However the variables "playerMark" and "player" are not recognized when I try to do this.